# Git diff with external exiftool does not output anything

Tags: git, diff, exif

I am trying to get some meta data from images with exiftool when I call `git diff`. I tried to follow [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) but the only result I get is

```
diff --git a/image.jpg b/image.jpg
index 4b0f38f..7fdca8e 100644
Binary files a/image.jpg and b/image.jpg differ
```

There's no EXIF data like how they claim, even though `exiftool image.jpg` works and returns EXIF data.

I added the `*.jpg diff=exif` to *.gitattributes* and I ran the command `git config diff.exif.textconv exiftool` but when I change the image, add it to the staging area and do `git diff --staged` that's all I get.

So, is this a bug, it's the documentation wrong or why don't I get the diff as I expect it?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are looking for differences between binary data. Can you create two text files and run a similar comparison?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; works fine for me: `git init test; cd test; curl http://placekitten.com/200/300 > kitten.jpg; git config diff.exif.textconv exiftool; echo '*.jpg diff=exif' > .gitattributes; git add .; git commit -m'First commit'; curl http://placekitten.com/400/300 > kitten.jpg; git add .; git diff --staged`

Comment: @Thomas - ACK, but OP failed (as shown) on commit diff, can you test it also?

Comment: @LazyBadger I don't understand. As far as I can see, OP ran `git diff --staged` just like I did (single hyphen in `-staged` is obviously a typo). What command do you want me to test?

Comment: @Thomas - diff file(s) in 2 changesets, I'll expect it'll fail. But I can be wrong

Comment: @Thomas - I see *now*: `--staged` requested, but I think diff-tool have to work in all cases and clean experiments is a must stage

Comment: @LazyBadger After the above commands, I ran `git commit -m'Change kitten'; git diff HEAD^ HEAD`. Getting diffed exiftool output as expected.

Comment: @Thomas - ACK. Can you move your results into separate answer, it will be useful for all?

Comment: @Thomas, it worked for me the first time, but only while it was in the staging area, once committed, doing a diff between commits did not display what exiftool returned. I will do a new test with a new repo

Comment: If you just see `Binary files differ` it's likely that Git did not run your textconv filter, which is often a case of some sort of hard to see typo.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get even *some* results, you must to use **proper things** in the **proper way**.

In your case, if you want to have custom diff-tool, you have to be sure, that this tool is able to work in some way in the required style at least outside Git. After careful reading of [docs for CLI-interface of exif](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html) I saw **nothing** about handling of exactly 2 objects for the purpose of comparison: only "single file" or "all in dir" when FILE is directory-name.

Prepare command line of pure exif for your task (in form `<TOOL> [--OPTIONS] FILE1 FILE2`), only in this case later it can be translated to diff-tool

Comment: The tool given to `diff.*.textconv` doesn't need to accept two files, it just needs to convert the binary to diffable text in some way.

Comment: @Thomas - yes, but this binary has to be *the correct* result of processing `*.jpg diff=`, isn't it? And, because it anyway diff, `exif FILE1 FILE2` must **do something**, which doesn't happen, AFAICS

Comment: Run the reproduction commands I posted above, and see for yourself :)